# Activating the iphone keyboard

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, keyboard

I cant believe that I haven't been able to find any documentation on this yet but I was wondering how to command the keyboard to activate and receive input from it. All of the examples I could find where for manipulating the keyboard that would pop up because of a text field being edited. Thanks

Comment: That is how you activate the keyboard. If you want to show it programmatically, make some control that has UIKeyboardTraits (or whatever it's called) the first responder and the keyboard will show.

Comment: Jason, you should re-enter this as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use the UIKeyInput protocol to request a keyboard without having to create a hidden text field.

```
@interface My : UIViewController <UIKeyInput> ...
```

and then something like this in the implementation

```
// Methods which make the keyboard work

- (BOOL) hasText
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)deleteBackward
{
    [self handleBackspace];
}

- (void) insertText:(NSString* )text
{
    int n = [text length];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        [self handleKey:[text characterAtIndex:i]];
    }
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

// Methods to manage the appearance of the keyboard

- (void) summonKeyboard
{
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void) dismissKeyboard
{
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Does it work? Conforming `UIKeyInput` protocol by `UIViewcontroller`

Answer (score 0):

I eventually decided to create a text field that is hidden from view and was selected by:

```
[text_input becomeFirstResponder];
```